# Create a column in pandas dataframe based on 1st row of each group

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'A'      :[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
        'B'     :[440,365,365,130,430,360,355,120]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 


    A   B
0   1   440
1   1   365
2   1   365
3   1   130
4   2   430
5   2   360
6   2   355
7   2   120
```

I want to create a column 'C' ans set it to 1 for first row of each group based on column 'A'.

Expected output:

```
    A   B     C
0   1   440   1
1   1   365   
2   1   365
3   1   130
4   2   430   1
5   2   360
6   2   355
7   2   120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (could be `0` or `""` instead of `None`)

```py
df["C"]=np.where(df["A"].eq(df["A"].shift()), None, 1)
```

Outputs:

```py
   A    B     C
0  1  440     1
1  1  365  None
2  1  365  None
3  1  130  None
4  2  430     1
5  2  360  None
6  2  355  None
7  2  120  None
```